# Docker machine using generic driver: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority when trying to add remote host to local machine

Tags: docker, virtualbox, docker-machine

I have a set up where I want to manage a docker machine remotely.  The remote machine is a windows box and my local machine(where I want to manage from) is a Mac laptop.  I have created the Virtualbox on the Windows host with docker-machine create and it appears to be working fine.

I then tried to add the remote host to my local machine using the following command:

```
docker-machine create \
 --driver generic \
 --generic-ip-address=10.0.0.9 \
 --generic-ssh-key=/path/to/mykey/id_rsa
```

Basically this command times out and when I do a

```
docker-machine ls
```

I get the following output. It's complaining about a GET request:

> https://10.0.0.9:2376/v1.15/version: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority.

I'm using the certs generated by docker-machine from the windows machine and I've included them in my local machines .docker/machine/machines/windows directory.

```
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
default   -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v1.10.3   
windows   -        generic      Running   tcp://10.0.0.9:2376                             Unknown   Unable to query docker version: Get https://10.0.0.9:2376/v1.15/version: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I've searched and searched for a resolution to this and no matter what I try, I cannot connect this docker-machine to the machine on my mac.  Does anyone have any insight into how I might fix this?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else is having this problem, the solution is:

`docker-machine regenerate-certs windows`

Where `windows` is the name of the machine with bad cert.